# converting a string array with letters into an int array in java

Tags: java, arrays, string, integer, int

Ok im going to try and explain my problem here and what I need to do is convert a string array into an int array.

Here is part of what I have (well the initial set up)

```
   System.out.println("Please enter a 4 digit number to be converted to decimal ");
    basenumber = input.next();

    temp = basenumber.split("");
    for(int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++)
        System.out.println(temp[i]);

    //int[] numValue = new int[temp.length];
    ArrayList<Integer>numValue = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for(int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++)
        if (temp[i].equals('0')) 
            numValue.add(0);
        else if (temp[i].equals('1')) 
            numValue.add(1);
                     ........
        else if (temp[i].equals('a') || temp[i].equals('A'))
            numValue.add(10);
                     .........
             for(int i = 0; i < numValue.size(); i++)
        System.out.print(numValue.get(i));
```

Basically what I am trying to do it set 0-9 as the actual numbers and then proceed to have a-z as 10-35 from the input string such as Z3A7 ideally would print as 35 3 10 7

Comment: so what is the question? you want to optimize the code or you are getting some problems?

Comment: The issue is that code I posted accepts the string and breaks it down into an array but that is all it does. It wont add values to a new array or change values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this single line in the loop (assuming user doesn't enter empty string):

```
int x = Character.isDigit(temp[i].charAt(0)) ?
        Integer.parseInt(temp[i]) : ((int) temp[i].toLowerCase().charAt(0)-87) ;

numValue.add( x );
```

**Explanation of the code above:**

- `temp[i].toLowerCase()` => z and Z will convert to the same value.
- `(int) temp[i].toLowerCase().charAt(0)` => *ASCII* code of character.
- `-87` => Substracting 87 for your specification.

Comment: @Jeff Ascii for "Z" is 122 so we should subtract 87 to get 35, op specifies that.

Comment: Yeah, I **just** realised that and was changin my comment when you posted yours. My bad...

Comment: I was trying this out me and a friend had discussed the ascii, but neither of us knew what to do about it. After I emplemented the code it threw an exception java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundersException: String index out of range: 0 @ java.lang.StringcharAt(Unknown Source) @ base.mainjava:38  and that is the first line of your code was there something I needed to import?

Comment: @madhatter I said that _"assuming user doesn't enter empty string"_ in my post above and it seems that your string is empty, i.e. _temp[i] = "";_ user should just enter digits(0-9) or characters(a-z and A-Z), in that case my code works perfect.

Comment: When I ran the code I entered the string asdf and that was what was returned could it be how the string array is saved and split?

Comment: I have had a definite improvement on the code after that line it is now passing the letters to the number, but I have an error with my loop or something because it is only passing the last digit of the array.

Comment: Just some good news to add I figured out the last issue with my loop and it runs as needed now thank you for all the help :)

Answer (score 5):

Try this in your loop:

```
Integer.parseInt(letter, 36);
```

This will interpret `letter` as a base36 number (0-9 + 26 letters).

```
Integer.parseInt("2", 36); // 2
Integer.parseInt("B", 36); // 11
Integer.parseInt("z", 36); // 35
```

Comment: Probably the easiest and most concise answer here.

Comment: would this result in an Integer.parseInt(""); for every line that needed? If so that is fine I'm just curious and checking all the possible answers.

Comment: @madhatter, you would need to pass each letter through `Integer.parseInt`

Answer (score 1):

Considering that you want to denote Z as 35, I have written the following function

**UPDATE :**

The ASCII value for Z is 90, so if you want to denote Z as 35 then you should subtract every character from 55 as (90-35=55):

```
public static int[] convertStringArraytoIntArray(String[] sarray) throws Exception {
    if (sarray != null) {
        int intarray[] = new int[sarray.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < sarray.length; i++) {
            if (sarray[i].matches("[a-zA-Z]")) {
                intarray[i] = (int) sarray[i].toUpperCase().charAt(0) - 55;
            } else {
                intarray[i] = Integer.parseInt(sarray[i]);
            }
        }
        return intarray;
    }
    return null;
}
```